The "Deleted" status filter is applied even if the "Show additional posts" is not applied
Steps to reproduce:

Go to the Staging Ground overview. Easiest way to see the problem is to make sure you have the applied the "New", "Published", "Off-Topic", "Duplicate", and "Deleted" filters. The last four are grouped under "Show archived posts" in the status filter. That makes 5 total:



Open the status filter, untick "Show archived posts", and apply the new filter selection.



Expected: The filters are everything else. In this case just "New".
Actual: The "Deleted" filter is still applied, so there are two active: "New" and "Deleted".


Additional information: Disabling the "Show archived posts" always removes "Published", "Off-topic", and "Duplicate" regardless of which are selected. This works as expected. Only "Deleted" has to be explicitly removed.
This might be because posts can be, for example, both "New" and also "Deleted". However, the filter selections do not work intuitively. If the "Deleted" is to be separate from "Archived posts", then it should not be grouped with the others. If grouped, it should behave the same way as the group.

A fix has been deployed. Deselecting "Show archived posts" will now uncheck the Deleted checkbox.
